# Multiple ajax request is made to fill table rows. How to sort the table columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I am making multiple ajax request using JQuery to populate table rows. How to sort the table column. I am using the first API to fetch all symbol's value. The second API is used to find the values of that particular symbol. These values are appended into table. I want to use sorting on columns of the table.
tablesorter() is is a function which sorts table is not working. This is working fine for a simple table.
Here is my code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


       
        // HTTPRequest
        var value = [];
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo"
        })
        .done(function(data){

            
            data.symbols.forEach(function(element, index) {

             value[index] = element.symbol;
             $(".tablefriendsname").append("<tr><td>" + element.symbol + "</td></tr>");
             

                
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",

                    url: "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=" + data.symbols[index].symbol
                })
                .done(function(data2){
                
                    $(".tablefriendsname2").append("<tr><td>" + data2.priceChange + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".priceChangePercent").append("<tr><td>" + data2.priceChangePercent + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".weightedAvgPrice").append("<tr><td>" + data2.weightedAvgPrice + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".prevClosePrice").append("<tr><td>" + data2.prevClosePrice + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".lastPrice").append("<tr><td>" + data2.lastPrice + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".lastQty").append("<tr><td>" + data2.lastQty + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".bidPrice").append("<tr><td>" + data2.bidPrice + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".bidQty").append("<tr><td>" + data2.bidQty + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".askPrice").append("<tr><td>" + data2.askPrice + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".askQty").append("<tr><td>" + data2.askQty + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".openPrice").append("<tr><td>" + data2.openPrice + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".highPrice").append("<tr><td>" + data2.highPrice + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".lowPrice").append("<tr><td>" + data2.lowPrice + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".volume").append("<tr><td>" + data2.volume + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".quoteVolume").append("<tr><td>" + data2.quoteVolume + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".openTime").append("<tr><td>" + data2.openTime + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".closeTime").append("<tr><td>" + data2.closeTime + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".firstId").append("<tr><td>" + data2.firstId + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".lastId").append("<tr><td>" + data2.lastId + "</td></tr>");
                    $(".count").append("<tr><td>" + data2.count + "</td></tr>");
                    $('#myTable').trigger('update');
                    
                })  // closed Inner done
        })  // CLOSE FOREACh
        });   // CLOSE outer DONE

        <!-- Sorting Columns -->
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter();
    });

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.29.5/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Crypto Api Fetch</title>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th class="">symbol</th>
    <th class="">priceChangePercent</th> 
    <th class="">weightedAvgPrice</th> 
    <th class="">prevClosePrice</th> 
    <th class="">lastPrice</th> 
    <th class="">lastQty</th> 
    <th class="">bidPrice</th> 
    <th class="">bidQty</th> 
    <th class="">askPrice</th> 
    <th class="">askQty</th> 
    <th class="">openPrice</th> 
    <th class="">highPrice</th> 
    <th class="">lowPrice</th> 
    <th class="">volume</th> 
    <th class="">quoteVolume</th> 
    <th class="">openTime</th> 
    <th class="">closeTime</th> 
    <th class="">firstId</th> 
    <th class="">lastId</th> 
    <th class="">count</th> 
    
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr class="">
    <td class="tablefriendsname"></td>
    <td class="tablefriendsname2"></td>
    <td class="priceChangePercent"></td>
    <td class="weightedAvgPrice"></td>
    <td class="prevClosePrice"></td>
    <td class="lastPrice"></td>
    <td class="lastQty"></td>
    <td class="bidPrice"></td>
    <td class="bidQty"></td>
    <td class="askPrice"></td>
    <td class="askQty"></td>
    <td class="openPrice"></td>
    <td class="highPrice"></td>
    <td class="lowPrice"></td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="quoteVolume"></td>
    <td class="openTime"></td>
    <td class="closeTime"></td>
    <td class="firstId"></td>
    <td class="lastId"></td>
    <td class="count"></td>
    
</tr>

</tbody> 
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load jQuery first.
2. Don't append a row into a cell; create a row string, add each cell, then append it to the table:

   ```
   .done(function(data2){
     var tr = '<tr><td class="symbol">' + element.symbol + '</td>';
     // array of each table column in order
     ['priceChangePercent', ..., 'count'].forEach(item => {
       tr += '<td class="' + item + '">' + data2[item] + '</td>';
     });
     $('#mytable).append(tr).trigger('update');
   });
   ```